# Authentication with google as well as direct login

Tags: feature-request, authentication

I have my stackexchange account with google authentication. But in some net work gmail is blocked. So is there any way to maintain the same account with dual authentication.Like google login as well as direct stackexchange login?

Comment: You can add additional OpenId providers to your account. Go to your profile, to the "Edit Profile & Settings" section, then to "My Logins" - you can add them there. (on some sites, there will be a link "my logins" near the top of the profile)